# How to save multiple records in cakephp 3.4.12

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i am trying to save multiple records in to single table. But facing problem while saving the form data. The problem might be with the form elements. please help me on this issue

**Controller save method**

```
        $data = $this->request->data();
        $stockin = TableRegistry::get('Stockin');
        $entities= $stockin->newEntities($data);
        $stockin->saveMany($entities);
```

Form

```
echo $this->Form->input("stockin.$i.date", [ 'value' => $stockindate]); 
echo $this->Form->input("stockin.$i.product_id", [ 'value' => $prod->id]);
echo $this->Form->input("stockin.$i.quantity", ['label' => false] ); 
echo $this->Form->input("stockin.$i.harvested", ['options' => 
$harvested,'label' => false]);  
echo $this->Form->input("stockin.$i.price", [ 'label' => false]);
```

Post array value is

```
 [
'stockin' => [
    (int) 0 => [
        'date' => '2017-08-18',
        'product_id' => '3',
        'quantity' => '1',
        'harvested' => 'k',
        'price' => '1212'
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'date' => '2017-08-18',
        'product_id' => '2',
        'quantity' => '2112',
        'harvested' => 'k',
        'price' => '12312'
    ],
    (int) 2 => [
        'date' => '2017-08-18',
        'product_id' => '1',
        'quantity' => '12',
        'harvested' => 'k',
        'price' => '12'
    ]
]
```

]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$data`, you need to mention `$data['stockin']`

```
$data       =    $this->request->data();
$stockin    =    TableRegistry::get('Stockin');
$entities   =    $stockin->newEntities($data['stockin']); // Modify this line
$stockin->saveMany($entities);
```